# PHP For Loop Confusion

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Am new to the world of coding and it is my first time understanding loops. I saw an example at a website and am utterly confused by the result.

```
/* Sample Code 1 */

$counter=0
$start=1

for($start;$start<11;start++) {
   $counter=$counter+1;
   print $counter;
}
```

This gives me the result of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Now if I update the code as follows

```
/* Sample Code 2 */

$counter=11;
$start=1;

for($start;$start<11;start++) {
   $counter=$counter+1;
   print $counter;
}
```

This gives me the result 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

However if I update the code as follows

```
/* Sample Code 3 */

$counter=11;
$start=1;

for($start;$start<11;start++) {
   $counter=$counter-1;
   print $counter;
}
```

I get the result 10,9,8.7.6,5,4,3,2,1

Please correct me if I am wrong

If the variable $counter has the value of 11, I am essentially start the increment at 11+1 in the code $counter=$counter+1. Is that correct?

But what confuses me is that how is the result in Sample Code 2 possible if my end value in the FOR loop is $start<11. Doesn't this mean it has to be less than 11?

Comment: You're confusign `counter` with `start`.

Comment: What SLaks said. `$start` DOES have to be less than 11, and it is by the end of that loop, even though you're incrementing `$counter`. `$start` isn't a special variable or anything, the only reason it's being used as the condition in the loop is that you specified it that way in your `for(...)` line.

Comment: Are you sure for the result in sample code2 or just a typo error. It should have 21 as the last value. And the $start<11 is for the loop termination condition. Your result is base on $counter which will do arithmetic operation while the loop condition is true.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. There is a 21 but that is not causing my confusion

Answer (score 0):

When you start the loop, `$start` is less than 11.  Then it is incremented at the end of the iteration.  Then, the loop ends if it has reached 11.

That is, if `$start` is 10, then it will enter the loop.  It reaches 11, so the `for` statement exits the loop.  It is 11 when the loop ends.

Comment: remember, it's logically the same as `while($start<11){$start = $start + 1;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description i wrote

```
for (//declare loop
$start = 0; //declare starting value and the value to store it in
$start < 10; // Each time it comes through, if $start is under 10, do the loop. if it is 10, exit
$start++ //Increment $start by 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you're missing "21" in your second example results.
Could this be the cause of your confusion?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. There is a 21 but that is not causing my confusion

Comment: Then just as everyone is stating, you could just be confusing the iterator with the counter. Unless you can elaborate more on the point that's causing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an explanation from all example above:

**Sample Code 1**

```
$counter=0;
$start=1;
```

This is variable declaration to declare and initialize both variable.

```
for($start;$start<11;start++) {
    $counter=$counter+1;
```

`for loop` has structure:

```
for({loop initialization}; {loop condition}; {per loop process}){
    //the rest of loop process
}
```

**Explanation**:

- As you can see, example #1 start loop from 1 (taken from `$start = 1`) and doing `loop for as long as $start is smaller than 11`. To prevent it from looping forever, that code add `$start++` which translate to `$start = $start + 1`. This way, for every loop, `$start` is added by 1.
- the `loop condition` has to return `true` in order the loop to run. If it return `false`, loop will quit.

Now, let's examine what's inside that loop:

```
$counter=$counter+1;
print $counter;
```

You see there: `$counter=$counter+1`. It means, you increment $counter by one for every loop and print the resulting `$counter`.

Let's breakdown the process (we start loop # with `1` as it's what's defined by `$start = 1`):

```
loop #   $start  ($start < 11?)  $counter ($counter = $counter + 1)
1        1       Y               1
2        2       Y               2
3        3       Y               3
4        4       Y               4
5        5       Y               5
6        6       Y               6
7        7       Y               7
8        8       Y               8
9        9       Y               9
10       10      Y               10
11       11      N               11
```

From process breakdown above, we can see that condition (`$start < 11`) is result in `false` on loop #11. That's why the result is `1..10`, not `1..11`.

Same goes with **Example #2**:

```
$counter=11;
$start=1;
```

Loop structure:

```
for($start;$start<11;start++) {
    $counter=$counter+1;
```

Let's breakdown this process:

```
loop #   $start  ($start < 11?)  $counter ($counter = $counter + 1)
1        1       Y               12
2        2       Y               13
3        3       Y               14
4        4       Y               15
5        5       Y               16
6        6       Y               17
7        7       Y               18
8        8       Y               19
9        9       Y               20
10       10      Y               21
11       11      N               22
```

This will output `12..21`. Because when loop #11 occured, it check that `$start < 11` is `false`. Therefore, loop quit.

Comment: Thanks Silent. Your example helped clarify it. Essentially the declarations within the for statement e.g. for(loop initialization, loop condition, loop increment) define the length of the loop e.g. 1..10. Thanks so much. Makes so much more sense. Now if I changed the logic, please correct me if I am wrong

$counter=0
$start=1

for($start;$start<11;start--) {
$counter=$counter+1
print $counter
}

It would fall over because the start value is 1 and I am indicating it to decrement. Is that right?

Comment: No, with that code, you'll end up doing infinite loop. Because, $start < 11 will always return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Please analyze your code.. you have a clear confusion b/w $start and $ counter variable. please use var_dump so as to see what your variables are going through